# Problems with indefinite articles

Tags: articles

Why do we use the indefinite article *a* in the following phrase, rather than the definite article?

> If that method is called on a multi element Navigator then **a** SingleElementNavigatorOnlyMethodException is thrown.

I'm interested in the "a SingleElementNavigatorOnlyMethodException is thrown" part.

Comment: It's referring to a new instance, not one that had been referred to previously.

Comment: It's often written either way. Unless there's a previously mentioned exception, there's no confusion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any simple rules for choosing the definite vs. indefinite (vs. none) article?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-choosing-the-definite-vs-indefinite-vs-none-a)

Comment: @Mitch please tell me what should I write if I'm reporting a bug and there was an exception thrown during the execution of a program? An exception is thrown or the exception is thrown. Thank you

Comment: @ВячеславПегаскин 'a/an'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *SingleElementNavigatorOnlyMethodException* **class** creates a *SingleElementNavigatorOnlyMethodException* **object**, so the noun in question would be definite (singular) if referring to the class, but indefinite if referring to an object created from the class.

Comment: @JohnMark Perry Thank you. Please tell me what should I write if I'm reporting a bug and there was an exception thrown during the execution of a program? An exception is thrown or the exception is thrown.